# how to make an observable in react with other library

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

i have a component which return a `<TextInput />` that i import from other library. the TextInput has a `onChange` prop which take a function `function(value) { // do something with value}`.so how can i make an observable with that `value` and use that observable anywhere?

```
import TextInput from 'otherLibrary';
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

export default class MyComponent extends PureComponent {

    handleTextChange = (value) => {
        this.observable = Rx.observable.from(value).do(() => console.log(value))
        // how to make an observable with `value`? If i just make it like this, every time input a letter in the TextInput will make a new observable, that's not correct.
    }
    render() {

        return (

                    <TextInput
                        defaultValue=""
                        onChange={this.handleTextChange}
                    />

        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your component is a react compoment, in onChange you could store this in the component's state using

```
this.setState({textInputValue: value})
```

(to get the correct this you need to change the onchange callback to the following:)

```
<TextInput
        defaultValue=""
        onChange={this.handleTextChange.bind(this)}
/>
```

Now, whenever that state changes, and you are for example, passing that state as a prop to another component, that component will re-render.

To get the actual value out of the textinput in on change if I recall correctly, you should use value.target.value, and maybe rename the value parameter to something else to avoid confusion, like

```
handleChange = (e) => {..

value= e.target.value
```

Comment: actually i want to make the value into an observable in rxjs. so is there any way to do so ?

Comment: @Downpooooour Unfortunately, I have no experience with this library, so I can not help you there :(